# Check whether every item in an array is a power of 2

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to put this problem together,

> Return an array containing all indices that are powers of 2

What I have below so far, I know modulo is probably the wrong operate, but I was trying to make it work. I'm not sure what else to try here.

```
function secondPower(arr) {
   
    let newarr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] / (2 ** i) === 1){
      newarr.push(i);
       }
  }
  return newarr;
}

[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Math.log2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2) to check whether the number is a power of 2, and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check whether every item in the array matches a condition:

```js
function isPowerOf2(x) {
    return Math.log2(x) % 1 === 0;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 16]
const arr2 = [2, 4, 8]

function isArrAllPowerOf2(arr){
  return arr.every(isPowerOf2)
}

console.log(isArrAllPowerOf2(arr))
console.log(isArrAllPowerOf2(arr2))
```

Comment: Note: `y % 1 == 0` returns true if y is a whole number.

Comment: Couldn't you just start from index 1 (or 2) and multiply that index by 2 on each iteration? *edit* - the question is not really clear, so I don't know. It says *indices* but the OP code seems to imply that it's supposed to be *values* in the array.